# avplayer has no sounds when play video

Tags: ios, avplayer

Here is all my code for play a mp4,the mp4 is playing but no sounds out

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer!
var player:AVPlayer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("huoguo", ofType: "mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * 9 / 16)
    self.containerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    //self.playerLayer.player?.volume = 1
    self.playerLayer.player?.play()
}
}
```

i'm sure it has sounds,because i can hear when play the mp4 using VLC,  did i miss something ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Check your phone is silent mode or not. If it is silent try add code below to `viewDidLoad`:

Swift 2.3

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: [])
```

Swift 3

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
```

Swift 4.2

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [])
```

Or just

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
```

Comment: Note to self... make sure that the video you are trying to get to play sounds actually has sounds in it. FFS! Thanks :D

Comment: Ok, my phone is not on silent but the audio in the avPlayer is not sounding. It's not about silent mode. I don't want to bypass a users' choice to silence the phone. I just want the audio from an avPlayer to sound.

Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 34):

For Swift 4.2, put following lines in `viewDidLoad`

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
}
catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
}
```

For Swift 5

```
do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
           }
           catch {
               print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
           }
```

Answer (score 14):

**Easiest answer:**

Check if the iPhone has silent mode engaged, it is a button above the 2 top left buttons. A toggle switch that allows silent mode.

Comment: I wasted hours on that. I think when you pressing the sound up button and iOS showing sound level but do not creates any sound because of silent mode is misleading.

Answer (score 6):

I had multiple view controllers that needed to play audio even when the device what set to mute. So instead of updating every single `viewDidLoad`, I added the following to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the *AppDelegate.swift* file.

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
```

Notes:

- import `AVFoundation`
- I didn't need any other error catching so I just used `try?`.
- I am supporting down to iOS 9. Gang Fang's answer required iOS 10. Only using the single parameter as I did above, though, worked fine for iOS 9.
- Tested with Swift 5

Answer (score 4):

Its working 100% please try this  import AVKit ,
import AVFoundation and put below code in viewDidLoad() Method.

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [])
    }
    catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with accepted answer but unfortunately it didn't works for me, failed with below error:

**type 'String' has no member 'playback**

Then i jump to the definition and found that it takes String value as parameter,
use below code if you have same error

```
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
        }
```